# Jest - Test suite failed to run with unexpected token on import module - TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I have a test on a Vite & TypeScript project which fails to run.

I have been working on this issue trying to solve it with several configurations, however, I haven't been able to solve it.

```
ts-jest[ts-jest-transformer] (WARN) Define `ts-jest` config under `globals` is deprecated. Please do
transform: {
    <transform_regex>: ['ts-jest', { /* ts-jest config goes here in Jest */ }],
},
ts-jest[backports] (WARN) "[jest-config].globals.ts-jest.tsConfig" is deprecated, use "[jest-config].globals.ts-jest.tsconfig" instead.
ts-jest[backports] (WARN) Your Jest configuration is outdated. Use the CLI to help migrating it: ts-jest config:migrate <config-file>.
ts-jest[config] (WARN) message TS151001: If you have issues related to imports, you should consider setting `esModuleInterop` to `true` in your TypeScript configuration file (usually `tsconfig.json`). See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2018/01/31/announcing-typescript-2-7/#easier-ecmascript-module-interoperability for more information.
 FAIL  __tests__/components/Header.test.tsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
    For information about custom transformations, see:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

    Details:

    /Users/xxxx/Code/xxxx/xxxxx/src/assets/fonts/ABCMonumentGrotesk-Regular.woff2:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){wOF2


    SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

      1 | import { createGlobalStyle } from 'styled-components';
      2 |
    > 3 | import ABCWoff2Regular from '../assets/fonts/ABCMonumentGrotesk-Regular.woff2';
        | ^
      4 | import ABCWoffRegular from '../assets/fonts/ABCMonumentGrotesk-Regular.woff';
      5 | import ABCWoff2Medium from '../assets/fonts/ABCMonumentGrotesk-Medium.woff2';
      6 | import ABCWoffMedium from '../assets/fonts/ABCMonumentGrotesk-Medium.woff';

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1495:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/styles/FontFamily.ts:3:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/styles/index.ts:2:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/Logo.tsx:3:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/index.ts:2:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (__tests__/components/Header.test.tsx:4:1)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.555 s
```

The above error has the following configuration:

Notice that `__tests__` folder is on the same level that `src` folder.

[image: I have file structure such as this]

This is my .babelrc

```
{
  "plugins": ["syntax-dynamic-import", "transform-runtime"],
  "presets": [
    [
      "es2015",
      {
        "modules": false
      }
    ],
    "react",
    "stage-0"
  ],
  "env": {
    "start": {
      "presets": ["react-hmre"]
    },
    "test": {
      "presets": ["es2015", "react", "stage-0"]
    }
  }
}
```

And my jest.config.js

```
export default {
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules'],
  transform: {
    '\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest',
    '\\.jsx?$': 'babel-jest', // if you have jsx tests too
  },
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      tsConfig: '<rootDir>/tsconfig.json',
    },
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\](?!lodash-es/).+\\.js$'],
};
```

My jest.setup.js

```
import 'whatwg-fetch';
```

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "podtunes",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "test": "jest --watchAll"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "localstorage-slim": "^2.4.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.11.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.21.8",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "^7.21.5",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.21.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.21.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.26",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.57.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.57.1",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.5.0",
    "eslint": "^8.38.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.3.4",
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^5.0.4",
    "vite": "^4.3.2",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^3.6.2"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "styled-components": "^5"
  }
}
```

Also, tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "moduleDirectories": ["node_modules", "src"],
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated it!

Comment: You have config to deal with TypeScript and JavaScript files, but nothing to deal with _fonts_. Have a look at e.g. https://jestjs.io/docs/webpack

Comment: Thank you so much @jonrsharpe for your reply. Actually, I am feeling a little bit idiot. I checked the Jest documentation, and I added the setup suggested, however, still have the error. Honestly, I don't know how I can setup it up.

Comment: I suggest you try to stub out those fonts. Add to your jest.config.js [moduleNameMapper](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#modulenamemapper-objectstring-string--arraystring) like `moduleNameMapper: { '.*\.woff.?': '<rootDir>/__tests__/dummyModule.js' }`. Note you have to create that dummyModule file as well.

Comment: @DanMacak, thank you for your reply.  Unfortunately still errors `({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import React from 'react';
                                                                                      ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` and `__tests__/dummyModule.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions.`

Comment: Can you share your repo? It would make things much easier.

Comment: Here you can find the repo https://github.com/webfer/podtunes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with your original issue - Jest was trying to parse your font (woff, woff2) files as JavaScript and it failed.

This is what Jest does by default, and we have to give it a hint that it shouldn't. Add to your `jest.config.js`:

```
moduleNameMapper: { '.*\\.woff.?': '<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js' }
```

This way, whenever Jest encounters a woff|woff2 file, it will import the `fileMock.js` instead, which is pure JS so there is no problem with parsing. So far so good.

The mistake you have made here however is in how you defined your `fileMock.js`:

```
export default 'test-file-stub';
```

On the first glance ok, but it produces the following `SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'`, which means Jest is not handling ES6 in mapped files well.

Fortunately, switching `fileMock.js` to CommonJS format fixes it:

```
module.exports = {};
```

Now the last issue was that you were not using a TypeScript preset for your tests. Without it TS can't be transpiled nor type-checked. This gave you `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`.

In order to fix that, I decided to use `ts-jest` in your tests since unlike the babel preset, it performs type-checking while running your tests. With that and some clean up, this is your `jest.config.js` now:

```
export default {
  preset: "ts-jest",
  testEnvironment: "jsdom",
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '.*\\.woff.?': '<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js',
  },
};
```

And voila, this will make your test transpilation work!

---

**Out of scope, but hell, let's make it work**

Notice that I added:

```
testEnvironment: "jsdom"
```

This is because you are doing UI tests and they require some kind of DOM implementation. The default environment for Jest is `node`, so I changed it to `jsdom` which provides the DOM needed for your UI testing.

You have to `yarn add -D jest-environment-jsdom` to round it up.

Also note that you can add as many extensions to `moduleNameMapper` as you need, I provided only one to keep it concise.

Comment: Dan Macak, Thank you so much for your help! Now it Works!!!!